# WPF - Disable tooltip when value is null or empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have this problem, i'm using telerik on WPF and a source on my grid and doing the correct bindings. I want to be able to disable the tooltip when the value of the binding is null or empty. How can it be done?
This is one example:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="GRIDVIEWCOLUMN_ENDDATE" Header="Data de Conclusão" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ClosedDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" IsVisible="False" Width="auto" IsFilterable="False">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClosedDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="13.667" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

[image]

Comment: is ToolTip has such a  IsVisible/IsEnable property or can you hide it with any parameter. If so, you can write a converter for this property

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a pretty old question but I was trying to hide empty tooltips and found a much simpler way to do so here: http://wpfthoughts.blogspot.com/2014/02/hiding-empty-tooltips.html.

Basically if you put a resource dictionary in App.xaml you can automatically hide all empty/null tooltips in your application.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger> 
            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}"> 
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/> 
            </Trigger> 
        </Style.Triggers> 
    </Style> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It is overkill if you only need it in one spot but it's a super simple fix that prevents you from having to add code to every page that has tooltips. Hopefully this helps someone out.

Answer (score 4):

Just bind the Visibility of your tooltip (in this case, you have provided a TextBlock) to the same property - ClosedDate, and use a converter to get the value based on your logic.

```
public class TooltipVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? Visibility.Collapsed :Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}
```

In your XAML, you would have something like this. You declare your converter as a static resource somewhere in your view, and later refer to it in your binding.

```
<converters:TooltipVisibilityConverter x:Key="TooltipVisibilityConverter"/>

<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="GRIDVIEWCOLUMN_ENDDATE" Header="Data de Conclusão" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ClosedDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" IsVisible="False" Width="auto" IsFilterable="False">
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClosedDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="13.667" Visibility="{Binding ClosedDate, Converter={StaticResource x:Key="TooltipVisibilityConverter"}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the post as an answer if it did.

Comment: well, another problem just happened. it seems that actually the textblock is collapsed, but the tooltip still pops up but i can notice is smaller so the textblock isnt visible.

Comment: Need to dig into the telerik documentation to find out. I will try to help when I'm at home.

Comment: Any news? i've been working out in other solution but couldnt do it.

Comment: @EchO, for your mentioned case with empty textblock, please check my above answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using a IValueConverter to show/hide the tooltip border

```
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="GRIDVIEWCOLUMN_ENDDATE" Header="Data de Conclusão" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ClosedDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" IsVisible="False" Width="auto" IsFilterable="False">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                 <Border Background="Black" Visibility="{Binding ClosedDate, Converter={StaticResource BorderVisible}}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClosedDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="13.667" />
                 </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

    class BorderVisibilitySetter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           //check if the control's content property is null or empty        
            if(value == null || value.ToString() == string.Empty)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, another problem just happened. it seems that actually the textblock is collapsed, but the tooltip still pops up but i can notice is smaller so the textblock isnt visible.

Comment: @EchO, for your mentioned case with empty textblock, please check my above answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the tooltip parent control IsEnabled to false will effectively prevent the tooltip to pop unless ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled is set to true.

Check george.zakaryan's answer, but instead of using a converter to bind the visibility of the tooltip textblock to its content, use a similar converter to Bind the IsEnabled property of the tooltip's parent to its Textblock's text.

```
public class StringToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? false : true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

in your xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <utils:StringToBoolConverter x:Key="StringToBoolConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SrcDrive, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding SrcDrive, Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" Width="400"  >
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SrcDrive, Mode=OneWay}"  />
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Native Telerik tooltip for GridView has a defect, which is even when you set `Visibility=Collapsed` it will still show an empty box (see below image):

**Code:**

```xml
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
        <telerik:GridViewColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>   
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Solution:**

Instead of using `null` check Converter, the approach that worked for me was to ***skip showing*** the tooltip when `TextBlock.ToolTipOpeningEvent` is triggering.

To do so in your `xaml.cs` do the following:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(GridViewCell),
           TextBlock.ToolTipOpeningEvent,
           new RoutedEventHandler(OnToolTipOpening));
    }

    private void OnToolTipOpening(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is GridViewCell cell)  // show tooltip only when text is trimmed
            e.Handled = !IsTextTrimmed(cell);
    }

    static bool IsTextTrimmed(GridViewCell cell) => cell?.Value.ToString().Length > 50;
}
```

That's it, and no need to write any additional logic to show/hide tooltips.